# Transforming escaped XML text into CDATA sections

Tags: xml, groovy, cdata

I'm looking to replace escaped XML sections with CDATA blocks, mainly to improve the readability of XML that unfortunately has to be read by a human.

```
// Input
def xml = '''
<search>
  <search-query>
    &lt;nested/&lt;
    &lt;xml/&lt;
  </search-query>
</search>
'''

def search = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def query = search."search-query"
query.replaceNode() {
  "search-query"() {
    // TODO how can I add a CDATA section here?
    //yieldUnescaped("<![CDATA[${query.text()}]]>")
  }
}

new XmlNodePrinter(preserveWhitespace:true).print(search)

// Expected
'''
<search>
  <search-query>
    <![CDATA[<nested/>
    <xml/>]]>
  </search-query>
</search>
'''
```

- Performance is not important
- I want to be able to use CDATA on only certain elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="search-query"/>
<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can replace cdata-section-elements with a space-separated list of element names.

Comment: Right tool for the job, I needed to preserve whitespace which the Groovy options didn't seem to do.

Ended up using xmlstarlet to do the transformation:
`$ xmlstarlet tr cdata.xsl input.xml > output.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get in Groovy is:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

// Input
def xml = '''
<search>
  <search-query>
    &lt;nested/&gt;
    &lt;xml/&gt;
  </search-query>
</search>
'''

def nodes = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

String newXml = XmlUtil.serialize( new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  search {
     nodes.'search-query'.each { x ->
      'search-query' {
        mkp.yieldUnescaped "<![CDATA[${x.children()}]]>"
      }
    }
  }
} )

println newXml
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<search>
  <search-query><![CDATA[[<nested/>
    <xml/>]]]></search-query>
</search>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way the built-in APIs can help you, since the `yield*` methods only apply when rendering out to a String (ie: using MarkupBuilder).  The `replaceNode` method only creates new in-memory nodes, which don't have any way to represent "raw" content.

However, given your limited sample, you might (and don't yell at me for suggesting this) be better off just doing string replacements:

```
// NOTE: using apache commons because I don't think there's a readily
//       accessible XML entity parser in Groovy's core libraries.
@Grab("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1")
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

// Input
def xml = '''
<search>
  <search-query>
    &lt;nested/&gt;
    &lt;xml/&gt;
  </search-query>
</search>
'''

def converted = xml.replaceAll(/<search-query>([^<]+)<\/search-query/) {
    def value = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(it[1])
    "<search-query><![CDATA[$value]]></search-query>"
}

assert converted == '''
<search>
  <search-query><![CDATA[
    <nested/>
    <xml/>
  ]]></search-query>>
</se
```

Excluding the Apache commons import, it's pretty clean.  If you don't want to see the whitespace around the nested content, you can change `unescapeXml(it[1])` to `unescapeXml(it[1].trim())`

This **only** works if the XML is properly escaped (meaning, no `<` show up in the section to be replaced), and **only** if you can safely determined which block to replace based on it's element.